# Overload method (specifically drawRect:) without subclassing

Tags: uiview, overloading, subclassing

I'm using a container UIView to house a UIImageView and do some custom drawing.  At this point I'd like to do some drawing on top of my subview.  So overriding drawRect: in my container UIView will only draw below the subviews.

Is there a way to overload drawRect: in my subview without subclassing it?

I think method swizzling may be the answer, but I'm hoping not.

(NOTE:  yes, it would have been smarter to have the UIView be the subview of the UIImageView, but unfortunately I'm committed to my mistake now.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you mean overload and not override?

Overloading -- creating a new method with the same basic name but different arguments and therefore a different selector -- could be accomplished by adding a new method category containing your new method to the existing class.

Overriding -- modifying the behavior of an existing method -- would require either monkey-patching the class's method table at runtime (for example, by swizzling) or subclassing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Overriding is definitely what I need, since drawRect: is never called directly.